# How to convert this method from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I am trying to mess around with some camera related tutorial I found on the Internet. The problem is that most of the tutorials are done in C#, whereas I need it to be in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). I have tried converting it using online converters, but it doesn't always recognise all the syntax therefore I get errors. How do I convert this into Visual Basic?

```
Loaded += (_, __) =>
    {
        Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode =
            Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;

        cam = new VideoCamera();
        cam.Initialized += (___, ____) =>
            {
                cam.LampEnabled = true;
                cam.StartRecording();
            };
        vCam.SetSource(cam);

        new Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

                    var files = isf.GetFileNames();
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Deleting... " + file);
                        isf.DeleteFile(file);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error cleaning up isolated storage: " + ex);
                }
            }).Start();
    };
```

This is the code I got from the converter:

```
Loaded += Function(_, __)
Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = _
    Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IdleDetectionMode.Disabled

cam = New VideoCamera()
cam.Initialized += Function(___, ____)
cam.LampEnabled = True
cam.StartRecording()

End Function

vCam.SetSource(cam)

New Thread(Function()
Try
    Dim isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Dim files = isf.GetFileNames()
    For Each file As var In files
        Debug.WriteLine("Deleting... " & Convert.ToString(file))
        isf.DeleteFile(file)
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.WriteLine("Error cleaning up isolated storage: " & ex)
End Try

End Function).Start()

End Function
```

Comment: Ive used a converter and its literally given me errors everywhere

Comment: I suggest posting what the converter did, so people can help narrow down the errors.

Comment: Ive added in the converter code

Comment: I'm wondering why the negative votes. I think this is a legitimate question. I voted it up to help offset the neg.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Roslny](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-816T). The converter is presented at 00 min 55 secs.

PS: underscores are a bad idea for a variable name.

Comment: The underscores are used to name function parameters that are never referenced, but he didn't write the code, so he probably didn't name them.

Answer (score 0):

Your converter doesn't seem to know what to do with the += operator or the underscores in VB.  They're wreaking havoc with the compiler.

Change

```
Loaded += Function(_, __) 
    Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IdleDetectionMode.Disabled
```

to

```
 AddHandler Loaded , Function(x as Object, y as Object) 
    Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = _
        Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IdleDetectionMode.Disabled
```

and change

```
cam.Initialized += Function(___, ____)
```

to

```
AddHandler cam.Initialized, Function(xx as Object, yy as Object)
```

Note you may need to change the `Object` signatures in the event handlers to match the actual event signatures, but everything else looks OK at a quick glance.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following (I used [Telerik Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)):

```
    Loaded += Function(_, __) Do
    Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IdleDetectionMode.Disabled

    cam = New VideoCamera()
    cam.Initialized += Function(___, ____) Do
        cam.LampEnabled = True
        cam.StartRecording()
    End Function
    vCam.SetSource(cam)


    New Thread(Function() Do
        Try
            Dim isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
            Dim files = isf.GetFileNames()
            For Each file As var In files
                Debug.WriteLine("Deleting... " + file)
                isf.DeleteFile(file)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error cleaning up isolated storage: " + ex)
        End Try
    End Function).Start()
End Function
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't think += works when adding an event handler.  You should use the AddHandler statement.